# Where would I find a PPA for the newest version of GIMP?

Tags: software-installation, ppa, gimp

Does anyone know of a PPA that has the development version of GIMP?
I would like to try out the new single window mode.

Comment: It's quite easy to just download the source and compile...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't been following GIMP development very closely, but it appears that in the latest development version, 2.7.1, "it is not possible to start up in single-window mode yet" ([2.7.1 release notes](http://www.gimp.org/release-notes/gimp-2.7.html)). I guess it's possible to enable it after starting though.

There is a [tutorial on How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12047/install-gimp-2.7.1-on-lucid-lynx-using-ppa/) explaining how to install 2.7.1 from a PPA and enable single-window mode.

A summary of how to add the PPA and upgrade Gimp:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: The version in that PPA is actually 2.7.3 now. But I installed it and it works fine. I'm already addicted to single-window mode.

Comment: @mac9416 Thanks. BTW the command is `add-apt-repository`

Comment: Actually, it's a common enough mistake that they made either one work. But `add-apt-repository` does read nicer.  :-)

Comment: I follow GIMP development very closely; it's not possible to _start_ in single window mode yet, but you can easily switch to it after launching GIMP. Just enable Window->Single Window mode.

Comment: After using that ppa, I can't open images with gimp by double-clicking them. I get the message "Service '/home/lovinglinux/.local/share/applications/gimp.desktop' is malformatted.". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm afraid not; sounds like something for a new question. Be sure to link to it here when you create it!

Comment: @lovinglinux, no incident like that here in v2.7.3 (U10.04)